# time complexity

Tags: алгоритм, time-complexity

Почему

```
if n <= 1:
    return 0
else:
    return f(n/2) + 1
```

по времени O(logN)

а

```
if n < 10:
    return n
else:
    n = n % 10
    return f(2*n)
```

по времени O(1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, в первом случае для ну очень большого `n` мы получаем примерно последовательность n, n/2, n/4 ... — т.е. порядка log(n) членов.

Во втором случае первый же вызов урезает n до значения, не превышающего 10, а ко второму вызову — 18. И никак больше 3 вызовов не получится — для 9. Т.е. количество вызовов ограничено константой для **любого** n. O(1).

Так понятнее?

Comment: поняла, спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо здесь имеет вид щелчка мышкой на треугольнике вверх слева от ответа; большое спасибо — щелчок на "птичке" там же...