# time complexity рекурсия

Tags: алгоритм, time-complexity

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему

```
def f(N):
  if(N <= 1):
    return 1
  else:
    x = f(N-1)
    y = f(N-2)
    return x+y
```

имеет O(2^n)

```
def f(N):
  if(N <= 0):
    return 2
  if(N <= 5):
    return f(N-1) * f(N-1)
  else:
    return f(5)*f(4)
```

имеет O(1)

Comment: Ну все, таки хватит :) @MBo прав, это уже третий вопрос на одну тему... Всё же очевидно, по большому счету...

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите вашу оценку сложности в вопросе. Если в ваших рассуждениях будут ошибки, мы поможем их исправить.

Comment: @Harry, надо вопрошающих подталкивать к правильной формулировке: "Я оценил так-то потому-то. Что в моей оценке не так?".

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy "Плюс стопицот" (с) :)

Comment: @russianbillie На прошлые ваши вопросы есть хорошие ответы, их неплохо было бы принять https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [time complexity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1532777/time-complexity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом случае, при достаточно большом N на каждом шаге будет создаваться две ветви рекурсии, каждая из которых, в свою очередь, создаст ещё две ветви, те ещё и так далее, поэтому количество вызовов функции можно оценить как O(2^N).

Во втором случае, для любого N будет вызваны f(5) и f(4), каждая из этих ветвей выполниться за определённое количество операций, всего вызовов будет 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 = 61 для f(5) и 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 = 31 для f(4), это константа, поэтому асимптотика O(1).